# Asana refresh token valid duration

Tags: asana

We are working on a project that uses Asana's API for integration. When a user authorizes the app to use Asana, we get the access token which is valid for an hour. In addition to that we also get a refresh token that can be used to renew the access token in future.

Could you please let us know how long will that refresh token stay valid for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refresh tokens are valid for 10 years, or until the user explicitly revokes the authorization.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Greg. How can we renew the refresh token if that expires?

Comment: When the refresh token expires you must obtain explicit authorization from the user again.

Comment: Thanks Greg, though I wish the refresh token was either alive for longer duration or had a way to refresh the refresh token itself

Comment: That's an excellent point, we'll consider providing a solution for longer-lived authorizations.